# Rails 6 with Pagy

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, rubygems

I'm working on implementing [pagy](https://rubygems.org/gems/pagy) into a Rails 6 app. I have the simple pagy_nav links working fine. Now, I'm trying to implement the pagy_combo_nav_js because some of my instances have thousands of items. I've followed the instructions [here](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras.html#javascript) for Webpacker, but I'm having no luck. The error I'm receiving is:

```
ReferenceError: erb is not defined
```

Has anyone successfully gotten pagy_combo_nav_js working in Rails 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually missing something like this in a environment header:
const erb = require('./loaders/erb');

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb
```